# How to get my button to appear in a form input box

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-search-appliance

Before I start, I'm open to different approaches so fire away.  Also, I'm using the Google Search Appliance, so I've got little ability to change the classes, ids and names of the elements I'm working with here.

I want to add a clear button inside the text box of the search form, just a grey 'x.'

The form code:

```
<div class="input-append">
  <form name="gs" id="suggestion_form" onsubmit="return (this.q.value == '') ? false : true;" action="search" method="GET">
    <input name="q" onkeyup="ss_handleKey(event)" type="text" maxLength="256" autocomplete="off" value="help"/>
      <button class="close" id="clear-button">
    <button name="btnG" class="btn" type="submit">
  ....
```

I tried appending it to the search box like so:

```
$("input[name=q]").append('<button id="clear-button" class="close" >x</button>');
```

The button doesn't show up at all despite it appearing in source, I can't even get the blue outline box.

So I tried appending it to the other input button like:

```
$("button[name=btnG]").append('<button id="clear-button" class="close" >x</button>');
```

The button appears unless I set the styling to be over the input box, then I just see the blue outline if it's highlighted in the source.

[image]

I tried setting z-index values like so, with no luck:

```
#clear-button {
    position:relative;
    left: -70px;
    z-index: 5;
}

input[name=q] {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}

button[name=btnG] {
    position:relative;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Anybody have a creative solution for this problem?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do something like this is to use a link tag as your button (using the appropriate styles to make your link tag look like a button). Otherwise, it gets super messy, unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a starting point for you.  It needs adjustment to be safe in your layout, but you don't need to know much to be able to make this work.  I used the styles as you provided them and simply added the closing  tag.  Colors and padding are just to make the styles more obvious.

```
.input-append{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.input-append .close{
    position: absolute;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    right: 40px;
    top: 12px;
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML as I used it:

```
<div class="input-append">
     <form name="gs" id="suggestion_form" action="search" method="GET">
         <input name="q" type="text" maxLength="256" autocomplete="off" value="help"/>
         <button class="close" id="clear-button">
         <button name="btnG" class="btn" type="submit">
     </form>
</div>
```

Once you have the elements surrounding this piece properly, you can replace "none" in the `background-image` declaration with an actual image link to a grey X.  You also can experiment with `position:relative;` depending on your whole layout, but `absolute` will tend to perform better if you can control the outer boundaries of your form.

Comment: @masedesign:  -- The OP is restricted to using the code as is.  While there are numerous ways to accomplish this if you can generate the code, in this case creating a link isn't an option.